# roc curve and speaker recognition

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance, roc, identification, speaker

I am using Euclidean distance for speaker recognition. I want to plot the ROC curve using `perfcurve` in MATLAB. Since the scores are the resulting euclidean distances, am I doing right? Thanks

`Labels=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1];
scores=[18.5573 15.3364 16.8427 19.6381 16.4195 17.3226 18.9520 21.6811 21.4013 22.3880];
[x,y]=perfcurve(Labels,scores,1);
plot(x,y);
xlabel('False positive rate'); ylabel( 'True positive rate')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did right.
Only sensitive point is that you have to understand the meaning of your scores. Is it higher the better or lower the better?
If its lower the better, then I would use `[x,y]=perfcurve(Labels,-scores,1);` instead

Comment: Indeed, a lower score denotes a 1 and a higher score denotes a 0. Thanks